# Mavensmate Install for Windows

Tags: mavensmate

I have installed Sublime Text 3 in My Computer for Windows 8.1 , but what should be my next step to use Salesforce plugin??

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: your next step would be to go to the MavensMate website(http://mavensmate.com/) and follow the instructions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support for Maven's Mate is provided on their website at mavensmate.com and on Gitbub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get and install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) for Sublime Text;
2. Using Package Control, install MavensMate using the command "Package Control: Install Package";
3. Install the Mavensmate-app software ([here](https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate-app/releases)).
4. Set up your project in the app.

Comment: Is github Necessary for This??

Comment: No. Github only serves as a host for the project and it's releases, since MM is open source software.